# Async and CancellationTokens/CancellationTokenSource memory-issue

Tags: asynchronous, memory-leaks, f#, mailboxprocessor, cancellationtokensource

I'm still on my memory-leak hunt and I noticed the following:

I have lots of live-instances of System.Threading.CancellationCallbackInfo-Objects coming from F#'s default-CancellationTokenSource (Async-Workflows).

The problem gets even worse if you declare a Source by yourself and use this inside a MailboxProcessor to span childs or tasks.

Seems like the GC cannot collect those spanned tasks/workflows because the CancellationTokenSource is holding references like this:
[image]

Most of those CancellationCallbackInfo-Objects gets to Gen2 - incredible as I just use local-references inside the MailboxProcessors-"loop" workflow ...

Is this a known issue and is there a solution/workaround?

For now I stoped using Cancellation-support and thread ManualResetEvents through the code for this ... not nice at all :(

Comment: Can you post a (minimal) sample that demonstrates the behaviour? It is hard to analyze the issue without being able to run that myself...

Comment: I'm not in the office ATM but I will try to plug something together as soon as I get to the code - but the core is not that difficult: this part comes straight from a MailboxProcessor I use as a workhorse for a "queued" IObservable implementation (you queue the values into the MailboxProcessors-inbox and the Processor "OnNext" all registered observers) - the part where tasks where involved is not inside a mailboxprocessor but in a tail-recursive asynchronous "Check"-Loop construct that spans tasks trying to asynchrounous ping a remote host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `StartChild`, there is a leak there (see also [this](http://t0yv0.blogspot.com/2011/12/f-frustration-more-async-memory-leaks.html)), which will be fixed in the next release.  You can work around it by using `StartAsTask`.

It is a good practice to use your own `CancellationTokenSource` to create a token, and explicitly pass the token to F# asyncs, so that you can `Dispose` the CTS on your own terms.

(If you see a different leak that doesn't involve `StartChild`, we'd love a small repro, so we can fix it!)

Comment: I will check this next thing tomorrow. I think that starting using the Task only created more Task<T> - objects in memory that linked to the same TokenSource (and those task-objects are really expensive memory-wise, so I stoped this) - I think that I spawn the sub-tasks with Async.Start right now, as I don't really need the result (first version just added an exception-handler with ContinueWith - it's now done by wraping the workflow)

Comment: I had indeed one instance of StartChild in there - removed this and cannot find a simple example locking things in memory ... so I guess I can mark your answer